# In outlook 2010 how to send multiple emails as reply all from sent items?

Tags: vba, email, outlook, thunderbird

i am not a techie, am florist

Need help in finding on how to reply all in outlook 2010 from sent items (multiple emails)

In outlook 2010, i want to follow up the emails i sent from sent folder with just one single mail, is there a way to add reply all button or a vba code where i can send reply all with one common template, i browsed through the forum found some insights, most of it is replying emails from inbox nothing for sent items.

if hit reply it comes back to the sender, i was looking for is select all mails from sent items and hit reply all.

any insight or links would be a great help
thank you,
Braydon

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can get the job done by automating Outlook using a VBA macro sub. Then you can [Create a button for a macro](http://www.howto-outlook.com/howto/macrobutton.htm).

The [Reply](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868875(v=office.15).aspx) method of the MailItem class creates a reply, pre-addressed to the original sender, from the original message. Then you can use the [Body](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865304(v=office.15).aspx) or [HTMLBody](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868941(v=office.15).aspx) properties to modify the message body and call the [Send](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff866779(v=office.15).aspx) method to send the e-mail message.

See [Getting Started with VBA in Outlook 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee814736(v=office.14).aspx) to get started quickly.